# How to achieve conditional validation with IDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

We have a configuration settings page in my MVVM application. One of the field(Property: BackupFolderPath) here has a TextBox control. We have done validation for this control using IDataErrorInfo. Validation is basically to check existence of this path.

What Validations have been implemented:

1. On application start up, existence of BackupFolderPath is checked. If this path does not exist, application gets navigated to the settings page and mark the control border red colored.
2. If user is on settings page and BackupFolderPath exists. Now, if we try to change the BackupFolderPath then validation again comes into picture and makes the control border color as Red.

What we want to modify now:

1. We want to keep the border color red only at the startup of application, if path does not exist. For second case, if path exists but user tries to change that from UI then we don't want to call the validation that means Textbox border color should not change to Red. We want to allow the user to change the path here.

XAML code snippet:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 <!--—Error Template to change the default behaviour-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <!-- —To display tooltip with the error-->
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="txtBackupFilePath" Text="{Binding Path=BackupFolderPath,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,0,155,0" Height="30" Width="500" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxLength="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

ViewModel code snippet:

```
 #region IDataErrorInfo Implementation

        public new string Error
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public new string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;
                switch (columnName)
                {                        
                    case "BackupFolderPath":
                       if (!Directory.Exists(BackupFolderPath))
                            result = "Configuration settings path: \'" + BackupFolderPath+ "\' not available !";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        #endregion

private string _backupFolderPath = string.Empty;
        public string BackupFolderPath
        {
            get { return _backupFolderPath ; }
            set
            {
                if (_backupFolderPath == value) return;

                _backupFolderPath = value; 
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BackupFolderPath);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So if the user types in an invalid directory, the border should *not* turn red, right? How do you set the BackupFolderPath initially?

Comment: Yes, the intention is to allow user to have a new directory that we will create through Save button on settings page(I have not shown it above  to keep it simple). Initially (1st time application startup), we provide some by default BackupFolderPath.

Comment: And how exactly are you "providing" this value?

Comment: The easy solution is simply to check to see if the backup path is empty, and if it is, set it to `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), MyCompanyName, MyApplicationName)` and be done with it.

Comment: @mm8: Initially this property remains empty. We ask user to provide the path & save it in an config file.

Comment: But the value must be read from the config somewhere.

Comment: @mm8: Yes, we write the path in Config file during save operation & check for physical existence of the path during application startup(using config file).

Answer (score 0):

I was initially confused why you were getting any error at all when they edit the path.
Then I noticed the updatesourcetrigger of the binding.
You have

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

It's doing the check as they type each letter. I can't see how that's a good plan.
If you remove that then the binding will transfer on lost focus and they'll get to type in the whole path. It will only light up if they put in an invalid path.

Maybe you ought to consider a filepicker rather than textbox.

Comment: You are right about UpdateSourceTrigger. In stead of using PropertyChanged, I tried Default. It does not show the red border during change of path in Textbox control.But problem with this approach is that during startup of application if some one deletes the physical path, it will again not color the border Red and that is not correct. We want red color border at startup of application, if path physically does not exist.

Comment: I don't know how you're instantiating your viewmodel initially but do so, present it to the view and then raise property change on the field. You may need to make your raisepropertychanged method public or something.